# TypeError: Cannot add new property '_currentlyShowing', js engine: hermes error when keyboard opens

Tags: react-native, keyboard

I have a React Native app with version 0.71. It builds without problem, but at runtime when I tap in any text input field and the keyboard opens I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR  TypeError: Cannot add new property '_currentlyShowing', js engine: hermes
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AF8V9.png)

This is the RN info log:

```
System:
    OS: macOS 13.2.1
    CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1 Pro
    Memory: 764.00 MB / 32.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 18.14.2 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.14.2/bin/node
    Yarn: 3.5.0 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 9.5.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.14.2/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2023.03.06.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.12.0 - /usr/local/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 22.2, iOS 16.2, macOS 13.1, tvOS 16.1, watchOS 9.1
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 28, 29, 31, 32, 33, 33
      Build Tools: 30.0.2, 30.0.3, 31.0.0, 33.0.0, 33.0.2, 34.0.0
      System Images: android-30 | Google APIs ARM 64 v8a
      Android NDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2022.1 AI-221.6008.13.2211.9619390
    Xcode: 14.2/14C18 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 11.0.18 - /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0 
    react-native: 0.71.4 => 0.71.4 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

I'm not sure if this is an error related to a library or react native itself.

I tried deleting node_modules, cleaning yarn cache, running gradlew clean and pod install, uninstalling the app from emulators, yet the error still happens.

Comment: Hi, did you find the answer to this issue? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Hi, yes, I finally realize that the issue was related with `react-native-reanimated` and `@gorhom/bottom-sheet` libraries. In the end this is the version of libraries that made it:

`"react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.9.0"`
`"react-native-reanimated": "~2.14.4"`
`"@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "5.0.0-alpha.0"`